# Listed item with GTC listing duration becomes unsold short time after it was listed

Tags: java, xml, soap, ebay-api

I list item using AddItemCall and it becomes available on my eBay account in active list, but after 1 or 1.5 hours that item becomes unsold despite the fact that in AddItemCallResponse I retrieve "End date" equals to one month + start date, so it shouldn't become unsold so fast.

Could you please help me to resolve this problem, so listed item will not become unsold so fast?

I am using eBay java SDK version 939.

Here is AddItemCallRequest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <ebl:RequesterCredentials xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">
         <ebl:eBayAuthToken>eBayAuthToken was removed in security purposes<ebl:eBayAuthToken>
      </ebl:RequesterCredentials>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <S:Body>
      <AddItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
         <Version>939</Version>
         <Item>
            <AutoPay>true</AutoPay>
            <Country>US</Country>
            <Currency>USD</Currency>
            <Description>Toto CARUSOE TOILET TANK COTTON Cotton White</Description>
            <ListingDuration>GTC</ListingDuration>
            <ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>
            <Location>Morton Grove, Illinois</Location>
            <PrimaryCategory>
               <CategoryID>20594</CategoryID>
            </PrimaryCategory>
            <ProductListingDetails>
               <UPC>739268183230</UPC>
               <BrandMPN>
                  <Brand>Toto</Brand>
                  <MPN>ST706#01</MPN>
               </BrandMPN>
            </ProductListingDetails>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <ShippingDetails>
               <CalculatedShippingRate>
                  <OriginatingPostalCode>60053</OriginatingPostalCode>
                  <PackagingHandlingCosts currencyID="USD">0.0</PackagingHandlingCosts>
                  <ShippingPackage>None</ShippingPackage>
               </CalculatedShippingRate>
               <ShippingServiceOptions>
                  <ShippingInsuranceCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingInsuranceCost>
                  <ShippingService>USPSFirstClass</ShippingService>
                  <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceCost>
                  <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
                  <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
                  <FreeShipping>true</FreeShipping>
               </ShippingServiceOptions>
               <ShippingServiceOptions>
                  <ShippingInsuranceCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingInsuranceCost>
                  <ShippingService>UPSGround</ShippingService>
                  <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceCost>
                  <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
                  <ShippingServicePriority>2</ShippingServicePriority>
                  <FreeShipping>true</FreeShipping>
               </ShippingServiceOptions>
               <ShippingServiceOptions>
                  <ShippingInsuranceCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingInsuranceCost>
                  <ShippingService>FedExHomeDelivery</ShippingService>
                  <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceCost>
                  <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
                  <ShippingServicePriority>3</ShippingServicePriority>
                  <FreeShipping>true</FreeShipping>
               </ShippingServiceOptions>
               <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
               <ExcludeShipToLocation>Alaska/Hawaii</ExcludeShipToLocation>
               <ExcludeShipToLocation>APO/FPO</ExcludeShipToLocation>
               <ExcludeShipToLocation>US Protectorates</ExcludeShipToLocation>
               <ExcludeShipToLocation>Africa</ExcludeShipToLocation>
               <ExcludeShipToLocation>Asia</ExcludeShipToLocation>
               <ExcludeShipToLocation>Central America and Caribbean</ExcludeShipToLocation>
               <ExcludeShipToLocation>Europe</ExcludeShipToLocation>
               <ExcludeShipToLocation>Middle East</ExcludeShipToLocation>
               <ExcludeShipToLocation>North America</ExcludeShipToLocation>
               <ExcludeShipToLocation>Oceania</ExcludeShipToLocation>
               <ExcludeShipToLocation>Southeast Asia</ExcludeShipToLocation>
               <ExcludeShipToLocation>South America</ExcludeShipToLocation>
               <ExcludeShipToLocation>PO Box</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            </ShippingDetails>
            <StartPrice currencyID="USD">82.38</StartPrice>
            <Title>Toto ST706#01 Toto CARUSOE TOILET TANK COTTON Cotton White</Title>
            <UseTaxTable>true</UseTaxTable>
            <SKU>HMWA-34413</SKU>
            <PictureDetails>
               <GalleryType>Gallery</GalleryType>
               <PictureURL>http://52.25.213.79/his/url?url=http://ec2-52-10-202-173.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/ImageFolder/resources/files/HM%20WALLACE/Images/Images_UPC/739268183230.jpg</PictureURL>
            </PictureDetails>
            <DispatchTimeMax>2</DispatchTimeMax>
            <ItemSpecifics>
               <NameValueList>
                  <Name>Brand</Name>
                  <Value>Toto</Value>
               </NameValueList>
               <NameValueList>
                  <Name>MPN</Name>
                  <Value>ST706#01</Value>
               </NameValueList>
            </ItemSpecifics>
            <BuyerRequirementDetails>
               <ShipToRegistrationCountry>true</ShipToRegistrationCountry>
               <MinimumFeedbackScore>-1</MinimumFeedbackScore>
               <LinkedPayPalAccount>true</LinkedPayPalAccount>
               <MaximumUnpaidItemStrikesInfo>
                  <Count>2</Count>
                  <Period>Days_30</Period>
               </MaximumUnpaidItemStrikesInfo>
               <MaximumBuyerPolicyViolations>
                  <Count>4</Count>
                  <Period>Days_30</Period>
               </MaximumBuyerPolicyViolations>
            </BuyerRequirementDetails>
            <ReturnPolicy>
               <RefundOption>MoneyBackOrReplacement</RefundOption>
               <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_14</ReturnsWithinOption>
               <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
               <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
               <RestockingFeeValueOption>Percent_20</RestockingFeeValueOption>
            </ReturnPolicy>
            <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
            <ShippingPackageDetails>
               <MeasurementUnit>English</MeasurementUnit>
               <PackageDepth measurementSystem="English" unit="inches">0.00</PackageDepth>
               <PackageLength measurementSystem="English" unit="inches">0.00</PackageLength>
               <PackageWidth measurementSystem="English" unit="inches">0.00</PackageWidth>
            </ShippingPackageDetails>
         </Item>
      </AddItemRequest>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

And here is appropriate AddItemCallResponse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header />
   <soapenv:Body>
      <AddItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
         <Timestamp>2016-03-24T20:40:16.028Z</Timestamp>
         <Ack>Warning</Ack>
         <Errors>
            <ShortMessage>Warning: Invalid free shipping for this service.</ShortMessage>
            <LongMessage>Warning: Free shipping is only applicable to the first shipping service. Free shipping will not be applied for this service.</LongMessage>
            <ErrorCode>51095</ErrorCode>
            <SeverityCode>Warning</SeverityCode>
            <ErrorParameters ParamID="0">
               <Value>FreeShipping</Value>
            </ErrorParameters>
            <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
         </Errors>
         <Errors>
            <ShortMessage>PayPal payment method added.</ShortMessage>
            <LongMessage>PayPal added as a payment method because you have set your preference to offer PayPal on all listings.</LongMessage>
            <ErrorCode>11012</ErrorCode>
            <SeverityCode>Warning</SeverityCode>
            <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
         </Errors>
         <Version>959</Version>
         <Build>E959_UNI_API5_17871548_R1</Build>
         <ItemID>201548340776</ItemID>
         <StartTime>2016-03-24T20:40:13.918Z</StartTime>
         <EndTime>2016-04-23T20:40:13.918Z</EndTime>
         <Fees>
            <Fee>
               <Name>AuctionLengthFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>BoldFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>BuyItNowFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>CategoryFeaturedFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>FeaturedFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>GalleryPlusFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>FeaturedGalleryFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>FixedPriceDurationFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>GalleryFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>GiftIconFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>HighLightFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>InsertionFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
               <PromotionalDiscount currencyID="USD">0.2</PromotionalDiscount>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>InternationalInsertionFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>ListingDesignerFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>ListingFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
               <PromotionalDiscount currencyID="USD">0.2</PromotionalDiscount>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>PhotoDisplayFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>PhotoFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>ReserveFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>SchedulingFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>SubtitleFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>BorderFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>ProPackBundleFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>BasicUpgradePackBundleFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>ValuePackBundleFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>PrivateListingFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>ProPackPlusBundleFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
            <Fee>
               <Name>MotorsGermanySearchFee</Name>
               <Fee currencyID="USD">0.0</Fee>
            </Fee>
         </Fees>
         <DiscountReason>SpecialOffer</DiscountReason>
      </AddItemResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this issue because my eBay account was connected to SellerCloud.
Disabling eBay account on SellerCloud resolved this issue.